# What can I do if everything with my 55-200mm macro lens is suddenly entirely blurry and the camera won't take pictures?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting, focus

I have a brand new Nikon D5500.

The 55-200mm macro lens is not working properly as far as I can tell.  It was acting funny the other day when I was trying to take pictures. The pictures were coming out a little blurry. I tried to use it today and it is not capturing whatsoever. There is no image and everything is extremely blurry.

I tried putting on the 18-55mm lens and it took pictures just fine. I changed the battery just to make sure, but when I put the macro lens back on my camera I get nothing. I put it on auto, like I always use mostly. It makes a bunch of noise like it's trying to focus when I partially push down the button to take the picture. Could there be something wrong with the lens already?

I've only had this camera for less than two weeks. It was taking great pictures with both lenses previous to today. Am I missing something like a setting or whatever?

Comment: What happens if you put the lens in manual focus mode? Do you see any change as you try to focus, even if it can't focus precisely right?

Comment: Is this the Tamron 55-200 Macro? And if so, how close is the camera from the subject? (minimum focus distance is 0.95m).

Comment: Manual focus is the same situation.   It just won't focus.  I was trying to take a distance shot picture outside.

Comment: I called Nikon to see if they could trouble shoot it for me.  I think we deducted that the lens is fritzed/flawed/defective for some reason.  It's very strange, since I have only had the camera for such a short period of time and nothing has ever happened to it.  It took great pics at first, but then a few days ago it would'nt focus very well, and then the following day, it won't focus at all. I just heard sounds inside it as it struggled to focus.    I guess I have to get a new one.   Bummer.   ;o(

Comment: Inkista: It is not the Tamron macro lens.   It's a Nikon/Nikkor lens.

Comment: VTC b/c your lens is likely broken for reasons no one is likely to be able to determine remotely. If you haven't already, take it in for replacement or repair.